# MATLAB Take the target sum as input and return the last odd number added to make the total greater than the target sum

Tags: matlab, for-loop, while-loop, series

for example: target sum = 8. The first sum greater than 8 is 1+3+5 = 9, so your function returns 5.

```
function last = lastnum(sum)
    ser = 1;
    asum = 1;
    if(sum > asum)
        ser = ser + 2;
        asum = asum + ser;
    else
        last = ser
end
```

This will not work on codycourse work, whats happening? Should I be using a while loop instead?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out!

```
function last = Chap20Prob11(sum)
ser = 1;
asum = 1;
while(sum >= asum)
ser = ser + 2;
asum = asum + ser;
end
last = ser
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the loop by something shorter, you can

1. create all odd numbers from `1` to your number `N` with

```
>> candidates = 1:2:N

candidates =

     1     3     5     7
```

2. Use [`cumsum`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) to get an array where each element is the sum of all previous elements up to the current element

```
>> cumsum(candidates)

ans =

     1     4     9    16
```

3. Find the first value in that array, which is larger than `N` with [`find`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html). The result of this function is the index, at which this occurs the first time, i.e. here at the third position in the array.

```
>> find(cumsum(candidates) > N, 1)

ans = 

     3
```

4. Use the index from before to extract that position (here: the third position) from the array

```
>> last = candidates(find(cumsum(candidates) > N, 1))

last = 

     5
```

So, you can write your function as

```
function last = Chap20Prob11(sum)
    candidates = 1:2:sum;
    last = candidates(find(cumsum(candidates) > sum, 1))
end
```